# Is it possible to add multi role in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, registration, role

I am building an education site, in that I want to add Teacher and Student as different user with some capabilities.  I tried many times, but only default role is working. How can I assign different role for student and teacher....? 
Tried many plugin also... At the time of new user registration, the role can select.

I tried these also

```
/* Add member role to the site */
add_role('member', 'Member', array(
'read' => true,
'edit_posts' => true,
'delete_posts' => true,
));

/* Add snypher role to the site */
add_role('snypher', 'Snypher', array(
'read' => true,
'edit_posts' => true,
'delete_posts' => true,
 ));

/* remove the unnecessary roles */
remove_role('subscriber');
remove_role('editor');
remove_role('author');
remove_role('contributor');
```

Is it possibile to add multi role in wordpresss?
    How can hide the default role?

please help me..

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create multi-role in WordPress. You can use [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) for creating different roles with different capabilities.